# Get handle of focused control from another applications window

Tags: c++, c, windows, delphi

I have an application has window this some controls (buttons, edits etc). I need to simulate user event (Like Tab click and input text). I'm using `keybd_event` to move focus between tab ordered controls (editboxes) and input text to them. But I need to know handle of current focused control (for example for get text from it or change its styles). How can I solve it?

ps
I'm writing Delphi now but it does not matter (Win-API everywhere the same).

Comment: Take a look at GetGuiThreadInfo()

Comment: Why did you decide to fake input instead of using the automation API?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Just curious - which automation API did you have in mind?

Comment: @MartynA UIAutomation

Comment: David, I need to use only WinApi without 3-d party solutions. Im working in company so it's not my decision

Comment: @user2598575 Er, UIAutomation is part of the Windows API. It never ceases to amaze me why so many people believe that faking input is the only way to interact with other programs. Anyway, it's obviously up to you to use whatever method you prefer. I personally would not do it the way you are electing to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See remarks section in [`GetFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)' documentation for an explanation of the below example.

```
function GetFocus: HWND;
var
  Wnd: HWND;
  TId, PId: DWORD;
begin
  Result := windows.GetFocus;
  if Result = 0 then begin
    Wnd := GetForegroundWindow;
    if Wnd <> 0 then begin
      TId := GetWindowThreadProcessId(Wnd, PId);
      if AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId, TId, True) then begin
        Result := windows.GetFocus;
        AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId, TId, False);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

[GetDlgItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  from the Win-API returns a value that is the window handle of the specified control.

Answer (score 0):

I converted pascal code of Sertac Akyuz to c++

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <psapi.h> // For access to GetModuleFileNameEx
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


#ifdef _UNICODE
#define tcout wcout
#define tcerr wcerr
#else
#define tcout cout
#define tcerr cerr
#endif

HWND GetFocusGlobal()
{
    HWND Wnd;
    HWND Result = NULL;
    DWORD TId, PId;

    Result = GetFocus();
    if (!Result)
    {
        Wnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        if(Wnd)
        {
            TId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(Wnd, &PId);
            if (AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), TId, TRUE))
            {
                Result = GetFocus();
                AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), TId, FALSE);
            }            
        }
    }
    return Result;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring state;

    while(1)
    {
        HWND focus_handle = GetFocusGlobal();

        if(focus_handle)
        {

            TCHAR text[MAX_PATH];
            GetClassName(focus_handle, text, MAX_PATH);

            const std::wstring cur_path(text);

            if(cur_path != state)
            {
                std::tcout << "new:" << focus_handle << " " << text << std::endl;
                state = cur_path;
            }

            }

        Sleep(50); // Sleep for 50 ms.
    }
}
```