# Send text into external textbox

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I'm building a virtual keyboard app and I want to send a text to the currently focused textbox (externally).

I tried to use the `SendInput` WinApi, but it has some problems with the space character. Sometimes it just ignores space characters for some reason.

I tried to use `SendMessage` with `WM_SETTEXT` and UI Automation `ValuePattern` but they both forget the caret position after insertion.
I also tried to use `SendMessage` with `EM_REPLACESEL` but it works on very few simple apps (like notepad), not for webpages in browsers.

What is the best and robust way to send a text to an external textbox as a virtual keyboard?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577348/get-handle-of-focused-control-from-another-applications-window

Comment: [`GetGUIThreadInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getguithreadinfo) and look for [`hwndFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-guithreadinfo)

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview). Works for windows that do not handle `WM_SETTEXT` the way you expect. And it works for UI's that don't have a native window.

Comment: What about `SendKeys.SendWait`

Comment: `SendKeys.SendWait` uses `SendInput` internally. For some reason there is a weird behaviour of randomly missing spaces... I can send "Hello World!" and sometimes get "HelloWorld!"

Comment: @IInspectable it seems that UI Automation ValuePattern set the text but can't save the caret position...

Comment: Neither does an implementation based on `SendInput` or sending `WM_SETTEXT`. If that is something you need, it has to go into the question.

Comment: You are right, I will add that. BTW, the `SendInput` does works like that, it just skip spaces sometimes...